# seeking stopper knot that is easy to tension and easy to untie

Tags: knots

I have first looked at other questions/answers here on stopper knots here and tried all of the ones suggested but I am seeking something better. My application is a single line through a hole. I want to be able to tension the line, so the act of tightening the knot does not create slack through the hole. I don't have slack through the hole before tying the knot. It is really not needing to hold any more tension that just pulling the rope taunt. I would also like easy untying. It seems a single overhand is maybe the best I can do thus far. Probably with a loop back (like how you tie your shoes) for even easier untying. This is a photo of it:
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "loop back" but my first thought is to use a slipped overhand knot.

Comment: Hi @MartinF - I added some clarification in words and a photo above. I tried the slipped overhand knot, but it is not easy to pull the slack out of it. Just pull the tail to easily untie it.

Comment: Is this a standard use of the term "stopper knot" in some group, field, or sport? In rock climbing in the US, when we refer to a stopper knot we just mean a knot that's bulky enough so that it can't pass through a belay device.

Comment: @BenCrowell I’m of the same opinion (UK). I thought that was what OP was asking for though; putting a line through a hole (in a board or wall or something) and a knot on the end to stop the line coming out again. Unless I’m mistaken.

Comment: Rolled back to restore an essential detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest a "slippery figure of eight" - although i'm not sure if that's the right canonical name for it.

[image]

It's my go to knot I use when trying to shorten guy lines on a tent or tarp - i.e. when I have a runner with a hole and can pull some of the line through, tie a stopper knot and then use the shortened guy line.

When taking the tent down, a brief pull of the loose end and the knot is undone despite the tension it was under in use.  And as a bonus, this knot can be tied in the middle of a line without needing access to the end of the rope.

Comment: I like this. It is pretty easy to tighten it up, and, of course, easy to untie. I'll go with your name for it too! Thanks.

Comment: @KevinBuchs - How is this any easier to tighten than an overhand knot?

Comment: Well it is my conclusion after comparing the two. With the Slippery-8, one can hold down with a loop and pull the knot tighter without letting the tension go on the other end.

Answer (score 2):

How about a peg that fits snugly into the hole with the rope--you pull tension on the rope and capture it with the peg, adding a half-hitch or slippery half hitch to lock it off.

[image]

Or an Italian (Munter) Hitch (ABoK #1818) around a peg, locked off with a cleat hitch as needed:

[image: Munter around peg][image: Munter around peg, locked off with cleat hitch]

I use this on a through-hole on an old sailing dingy with a missing stay.  It won't slip, won't pull through the hole, and will remain easy to untie, even under load.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that is a great answer and with good pictures.

Answer (score 1):

A cow hitch, when pulled tight, can both grip quite well and be slid along to take up the slack. (This one's not pulled tight.)

[image]

For quick release, make it slipped.

[image]

If it needs to grip more tightly, use a Prusik (ie, a cow hitch with extra turns).

[image]

Comment: This won't really fit my application. I'm not trying to tie a hitch/loop. I really need a stopper knot. This knot would not hold if you ran the line on the left margin through a hole and pulled on it.

Comment: @KevinBuchs - "It is really not needing to hold any more tension that just pulling the rope taunt."

Comment: Yes, and your knot will not keep the rope taunt. As soon as there is a little vibration it will start to slip.

Comment: This may not do for OP but it is likely to help others with an alike problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the barrel knot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRfjF5TcQbw.
This is used by climbers to make sure the rope can't pass through the hole in a belay device.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Welcome to Stack Exchange! Thanks for your answer. I tried it and it seems to be hard to tighten this knot without pulling on both ends of the rope. That wouldn't work for my application, where I want to maintain tension on one end.

Comment: you could also tie a clove hitch around a toggle